# Conditional type for react props with default optional value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I want to have conditional props types

When i try to pass a default value to my optional prop, which is inside the conditional type, the types break

```js
export type ChatBase = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

type ChatCardProps = { title: string; } &
  (
    | {
        chat: ChatBase & { createdBy: { displayName: string } };
        hideCreator?: false;
      }
    | {
        chat: ChatBase;
        hideCreator: true;
      }
  );

const Chat = ({ title, chat, hideCreator = false }: ChatCardProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      {!hideCreator && <p>{chat.createdBy.displayName}</p>}
      {/*                           ^? createdBy?: { displayName: string; } | undefined */}
    </div>
  )
}

const Chat2 = ({ title, chat, hideCreator }: ChatCardProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      {!hideCreator && <p>{chat.createdBy.displayName}</p>}
      {/*                          ^? createdBy?: { displayName: string; } */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Why when I pass an default value the logic breaks?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-browser-hgshpz?file=/src/App.tsx:349-350

Comment: Can you please add working snippet over here or maybe attache codesanbox link over here?

Comment: @PrashantShah you can check the link I added

Comment: It looks like a typescript bug

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using type casting here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-snow-2k8xfx?file=/src/App.tsx) link where I did some updating inside your code-sandbox snippet

Apart from that you can do it using generics here is the reference code snippet for that but it will change whole code and more efforts will be required in that case

```
 type ChatType<HasDisplayName extends boolean> = HasDisplayName extends true
  ? ChatBaseWithdisplayName
  : ChatBaseWithoutDisplayName;

// Usage with a condition
const hasDisplayName = true; // Example condition

const chat: ChatType<typeof hasDisplayName> = {
  title: "Chat Title",
  // ... other properties based on the selected type
};

// Alternatively, without a condition (always uses ChatBaseWithdisplayName)
const chatAlwaysDisplayName: ChatType<true> = {
  title: "Chat Title",
  // ... other properties based on ChatBaseWithdisplayName
};

const chatNoDisplayName: ChatType<false> = {
  title: "Chat Title",
  // ... other properties based on ChatBaseWithoutDisplayName
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is partial and I'm not sure what `CardProps` is, I made a scaled down example that seems to work. You can find it [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzQaRm).

Comment: I updated the code to remove CardProps. I don't think your example showcases my problem.

Comment: @Stavros thank you.

How about preparing a sample here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play and share it?

Comment: I have a codesandbox that illustrates my problem. it's in the question above

Comment: @Stavros thx. So the problem is that you can not access 'createdBy' without a warning?